# ObjectiveC-When I add custom class to userInfo of NSUserNotification, it may cause userInfo to become nil value?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

- macOS 12.2.1
- Xcode 13.3

I'm a beginner in Objective-C. When I try to create a local notification, I save an object of a custom class to the userInfo property of NSUserNotification, but the userInfo seems to be assigned to a nil value.
I will provide a simple code below to demonstrate this.

```objectivec
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyData : NSObject<NSSecureCoding>
@end
@implementation MyData{
    double data;
}
-(instancetype)initWithData:(double)data{
    [super init];
    self->data = data;
    return self;
}

+(BOOL)supportsSecureCoding{
    return YES;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeDouble:data forKey:@"data"];
}

-(nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super init]){
        self->data = [coder decodeDoubleForKey:@"data"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSUserNotification* n = [NSUserNotification new];
    MyData* myData = [[MyData alloc] initWithData: 1.0];
    n.userInfo = @{@"MyData":myData};
    assert(n.userInfo == nil);// nil userInfo
    
    n.userInfo = @{@"MyData":@"Other"};
    assert(n.userInfo != nil);// but not nil here.
    return 0;
}
// Why? How can I pass my custom object?
```

Comment: According to the doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsusernotification/1415675-userinfo?language=objc) `All items must be property list types or an exception is thrown.`, that could be the issue. Even if you are NS(Secure)Coding compliant, it's not of the initial types (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html). So encode `myData` into a `NSData` first?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the documentation of [`userInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsusernotification/1415675-userinfo?language=objc):

> All items must be property list types or an exception is thrown.

Does `MyData` is one of the property list types? No. The allowed types are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html).

Now, let's do some test:

```
NSUserNotification* n = [NSUserNotification new];

NSString *errorDescription = nil;

MyData* myData = [[MyData alloc] initWithData: 1.0];

// String: String
NSDictionary *basicDict = @{@"MyData": @"Other"};
n.userInfo = basicDict;
NSLog(@"UserInfo Basic: %@", n.userInfo);
id plistStrTest = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:basicDict
                                                             format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                   errorDescription:&errorDescription];
if (errorDescription) {
    NSLog(@"Error while serializing: %@", errorDescription);
}
NSLog(@"Plist Basic: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistStrTest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


// String: MyData
NSDictionary *rawDataDict = @{@"MyData": myData};
n.userInfo = rawDataDict;
NSLog(@"UserInfo Data: %@", n.userInfo);
errorDescription = nil;
id plistRawData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:rawDataDict
                                                             format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                   errorDescription:&errorDescription];
if (errorDescription) {
    NSLog(@"Error while serializing: %@", errorDescription);
}
NSLog(@"Plist Raw: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistRawData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


NSDictionary *combinedRawAndBasic = @{@"MyData":@"Other", @"MyData2": myData};
n.userInfo = combinedRawAndBasic;
NSLog(@"UserInfo Combined: %@", n.userInfo);
id plistCombined = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:combinedRawAndBasic
                                                                 format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                       errorDescription:&errorDescription];
if (errorDescription) {
    NSLog(@"Error while serializing: %@", errorDescription);
}
NSLog(@"Plist Combined: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistCombined encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


// With Encoding, i.e with NSData
NSError *encodingError = nil;
NSData *encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myData requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&encodingError];
if (encodingError) {
    NSLog(@"Error while encoding: %@", encodingError);
}
NSDictionary *encodedDict = @{@"MyData": @"Other", @"MyData2": encodedData};
n.userInfo = encodedDict;
NSLog(@"UserInfo encoded: %@", n.userInfo);
errorDescription = nil;
id plistEncodedData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:encodedDict
                                                                 format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                       errorDescription:&errorDescription];
if (errorDescription) {
    NSLog(@"Error while serializing: %@", errorDescription);
}
NSLog(@"Plist: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistEncodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

You'll see then, and it concords with the documentation that if you put directly a `MyData` object, it will reject all the dictionary. But not if you encode it first with `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Strangely, since the doc talks about an exception thrown, I would have a expect a `NSUncaughtException` in console and a crash, but there isn't, it's a silent one, that just reject the `userInfo` set.

You'll need later `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to decode the encoded data.